# Update model from database not updating metadata

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, database-metadata

My project has stopped updating the metadata when I add new tables or stored procedures. Its on Visual Studio 2017. with .net framework 4.6.1

I use the Update model from database wizard and after selecting the new item and clicking finish. If I check in the model browser i can see the new classes in the Model and in the model.store. Also, Its in the solution explorer .edmx. 
The problem is not all projects can reference the new items and i noticed the new items are not in the Entities Metadata.

Things i tried

1. Run custom tools on .tt files
2. clean all projects individually and rebuilt
3. closed application and open it

Please help

Comment: Did the update generate new classes, i.e. .cs files?

Comment: Yes they did, but not declared in metadata

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what the update did and didn't. Maybe you should show an image of what's visible (of the new tables) in de EDMX model browser and in the solution explorer. If classes (cs files) were generated then what does it mean that *not all projects can reference the new items*? And which EF version is this?

Comment: When I update the model with e.g a new stored procedure. I see in the edmx .tt and .content.tt. Also if I check in the model browser. Its added in the complex types and function imports. But if i go and right click on the entity declaration in the businesslogic application. it opens a class named Entities[from metadata]. this is not getting updated anymore. all my tables and sp are declared there apart from newly added ones.

Answer (score 2):

I have the entity framework (DB) in a separate project the is linked in the references.  I found the only thing that worked for me was to unlink the reference, rebuild and have it fail and re link the project.  SOOOO frustrating as this functionality used to work quite well.